# HTML .gitignore

Tags: node.js, api, github

I currently have my api keys and list id sitting in my app.js file. I am trying to add those API keys to another file and hide the file using .gitignore. But how do I do that and even if I hide the file in the new secret file how do I get those keys back in my original app.js file

Comment: Be aware that, if you previously commited your app.js file, secret may be still available in the file history

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is use an Environment File.
Environment files start with .env and allow you to save things that are specific to your working environment (such as sensitive keys).
If you are using nodejs, you can easily import the data from a .env file using require('dotenv').config().
These files are also ignored by the default .gitignore configuration.

Comment: So the environment file need not to be added in the .gitignore file and it will automatically be hidden?

Comment: Check your .gitignore file, it might already be there if you used git init. If not, you do need to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install a library called dotenv

```
npm i dotenv --save
```

Create a file called `.env` and place your API KEY in it and create `.gitignore` file place your `.env` in it

**Example**

Inside `.env` :

```
API_KEY= YOUR_APIKEY without quotation
```

Inside `.gitignore`:

```
.env
```

To use your API KEY inside app.js

Inside `app.js`:

```
require('dotenv').config()

let API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Using .env file**

- Install the dotenv npm package

  `npm install dotenv --save`
- Create a .env file at the root of your project and store your SECRET_KEY like shown below.

  SECRET_KEY="YOURSECRETKEYGOESHERE"

  To get the value from the key use the following code

  `require('dotenv').config()`

  `console.log(process.env)`

  For more information do check the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxKqx.png).

2. **Using .gitignore file**
   .gitignore file is used to add those files which you don't want to commit to your git repository. In this case, you can create a file called`.gitignore` and in that file add the file names which should not be committed.

`.gitignore`

```
.DS_Store
secrets.txt
.env

#This is comments(# used for comments)

*.txt  #this means all files with .txt extention will be ignored
```

To get the prebuild template for `.gitignore` files for nodeJs or any kind of project do check the repository down below.

https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: Please do not use screenshot. Paste the content of the file as markdown code snippet. Screenshot does not allow copy/pasting code and probably make search engines to not discover its content